# How to create multiple files of the same size from a variable?

Tags: file, shell, variables, split

I have a shell script with a variable which I create an output file as follows

```
Variable >> file.txt
Result:
file.txt 20 kilobytes
```

Then, I have to split that output file in several of the same size using the split instruction

Result:

```
file01.txt 10 kilobytes

file02.txt 10 kilobytes
```

My question is:
Is there any way to apply the equivalent of split instruction while creating the output file? This is the expected output:

```
Variable >> file.txt / / Adding here the code needed to do the split
```

Result:

```
file01.txt 10 kilobytes

file02.txt 10 kilobytes
```

Comment: Could you please post the "split instruction" you are using?

Comment: split -db70k directory/file.txt directory/file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An example,

```
echo $var | split -b 10240
```

You can specify the output file prefix like this:

```
echo $var | split -b 10240 - dir1/mysplits
```

which produces filenames dir1/mysplitsaa, dir1/mysplitsab, dir1/mysplitsac, ... You can also rename these files after split of course.

Comment: How do you specify the directory and the output file names  with this instruction?
With this instruction the script generates output files like this: x00, x02 ...

Answer (score 0):

You can chain any number of commands together by putting `&&` between them - this basically tells the shell that if the first command succeeded, then perform the second command.

Alternatively, you can "pipe" data from one command to the next. This is done with `|`, and essentially takes the output of the first command and passes it as input to the second command.

Comment: Typo? `&` does not chain commands together, it runs the specified command in the background. I think you meant `&&`.

Comment: Can you give me an example using "&&"?